# 100% CPU in Core Data operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

How it is possible that i get CPU 100% and block main thread in background queue. I do it like that:

Firstly i create context in custom setter:

```
-(void)setContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        _context = context;
    });
}
```

Then I download some data using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and then is my method to inserting:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishWithObject:(NSArray*)arrayOfObjects {

    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("myDispatch", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
                [self.context performBlock:^{
                    for(NSDictionary *dic in myArr) {
                        [Tournament  tournamentWithDictionary:dic inMOC:self.context];
                    }
                }];
            }

}
```

And here is my insert to `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
+(Tournament*)tournamentWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc {
 Tournament *finalElement;   

    if(!finalElement) {
        finalElement = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tournament" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        [finalElement setTournamentID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"ID"] integerValue]]];
    }
    return finalElement;
}
```

And I'm getting 100% CPU usage and my interface is block! Why?!

Comment: Are you sharing the persistent store with the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually profile your code to see what is consuming the CPU?

Also, how is your managed object context configured?   Specifically, what is the concurrency type?  Your use of a queue to cause the context to perform a block is going to be entirely pointless if the concurrency type is NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

I'd suggest you read [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385) closely.

---

Your use of that `dispatch_async` in the setter is both unnecessary and it will lead to a race condition with the use `dispatch_async` to a *different queue* in `connectionDidFinishWithObject:`.

I.e. your concurrency is busted.

Answer (score 2):

Run under the debugger and hit 'pause' to find out what the main thread is doing. Use Instruments to show which code is running to chew up CPU.

Comment: I know this is inserting to Core Data.I have a lot of objects, but why main thread is blocked with this code?

Comment: If you pause in the debugger, you will see which function is currently running or waiting in the main thread.  If you post that information, we may be able to answer your question about why the main thread is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet clear on how you're using Core Data on the main queue, if at all, but the usual cause of this is that:

1. you've used a SQLite persistent store;
2. you are accessing some `NSManagedObject` property on the main queue;
3. simultaneously you are saving on some other queue.

The access on your main queue necessitates a trip to the database, usually because the object you're accessing is currently a fault — though any other trip to the database would be just as problematic. So doing an `NSFetchRequest` explicitly or having an active `NSFetchedResultsController` that has to do some work, say, due to scrolling are both equivalent conditions.

Sadly SQLite isn't thread safe. Partly as a result you can't access the database while it is saving. Saving can take quite a long time if you've inserted a lot of entries, if you have complicated indices, or for a bunch of other reasons.

So the main queue wants a synchronous trip to the database but Core Data has to wait for the save to complete. Hence it has to block.